# searchDisplayController removes my searchtext

Tags: iphone

I need help with the searchDisplayController.
Right now I am using the searchDisplayController with textDidChange,
but whenever I press search or on one of the rows my search text is removed from the searchBar. 
After that it returns to textDidChange and I execute my code with an empty string.
Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    if(connectionStatus.boolNoConnection||connectionStatus.boolErrorConnection)
    {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = 2.5f;
        span.longitudeDelta = 2.5f;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = 52.30;
        location.longitude = 5.45;

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.span = span;
        region.center = location;
        [map setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        if (![geoArray count] == 0) {
            [map removeAnnotations:pins];
            [pins release];
            [pinPlacemark removeAllObjects];
            [self readArray:geoArray];  
            [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];   
        }
    }
}
```

I only call the searchdisplaycontroller here, nowhere else

Comment: It would help to see your code. one thing to look for is you don't need to modify the UISearchView text property really at all. My implementations ensure it is blank at init of the view and never change it after that. I do set the placeholder property to whatever is in text when the search button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need to see your code, but from what i have read, there is no need to change the search text.  Check your code to see if you are calling [[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setText:XXX] at all.  That allows you to modify the text in the search bar without running the search.